# How to downmix 6-channel DTS to stereo from the command line?

Tags: windows, linux, command-line, audio

I tried command `eac3to.exe src.dst dst.wav -down16 -down2` ([v.3.24](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=125966)) but it just re-produces the same 6ch audio without any warning.

Operating system: both Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

**Update:** See a solution below. But I'm still interested in a command line solution.

Comment: I tried also the DTS plugin for foobar2000 but I always get 6ch WAV's even with DSP "Convert 5.1 to mono" turned on.

Comment: Oh! I didn't turned on DSP "Convert 5.1 to mono" in the wav converter. Now I have reached the goal in Windows.